# Emacs Incremental search not jumping to next occurence

Tags: emacs

When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> and search for a text, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> again, it should incrementally jump to the next occurrence of the text. But it does not work for me anymore.

Here are my Emacs Info:

```
GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21)
 of 2014-10-20 on builder10-9.porkrind.org
```

My small init.el is at http://pastebin.com/XFEEA1i4

Edit: My installed packages is at http://pastebin.com/nFxquDE7
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Does the same problem occur when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: @nanny: Incremental search works with emacs -Q :). What have I done to lose it?

Comment: That means it's a problem with your init. The first thing I would try is to comment out Ergo Emacs mode setup (lines 46-48 on pastebin) and restart Emacs. See if that fixes it. Nothing else looks out of the ordinary to me.

Comment: As for all problems with your init file, the quickest and surest way to find the problem is to use **binary search**: Comment out 1/2 of it, then 3/4, then 7/8,... You can use `comment-region` to comment-out selected lines, and you can use `C-u` with the same command to uncomment the selection. This beats guessing pretty much all the time, in terms of speed and not just sureness. It might make you feel unclever, but it is *smart* to use binary search.